# migrating to v3.. serviceWorker

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

In my chrome extension manifest v2, I am storing my values in `window.object`.
Migrating to serviceWorkers would mean that I would no longer access to dom.

What method would you use to store a global variable that could be used by the background script fns?

Any advise?

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(() => {
  window._linkedin_pixel_data = {};
  const matchingUrls = ["<all_urls>"];
});
```

Comment: Simply declare a global variable and use its name without the `window.` prefix. Alternatively replace `window` with `globalThis`.

Comment: thanks wOxxOm. do you know the lifecycle of the global variable on serviceworker? It doesnt get the value like how the value persisted with window varible.

Comment: The worker terminates after 30 seconds since the last chrome event, so you need to use chrome.storage to save the data between runs, [example](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/storage/#asynchronous-preload-from-storage).